# Mobile Jquery collapsible div within itemtemplate of gridview not clipping internal div

Tags: gridview, html, jquery-mobile, itemtemplate

Mobile JQuery jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js
HTML 5
Asp.net 4.0

I have a gridview item-template where I have implemented the collapsible div from JQuery Mobile. In the h3 I have another div which I would like to clip because the label text can be quite long (I don't want to wrap). With my current set up the collapsible div is expanding the whole gridview past the screen boundary. I have tried a bunch of different CSS and inline styling at several levels but just cannot figure this one out. I'm sure it's a simple fix for someone else's eyes.

```asp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
  <link href="Styles/MB.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head> 
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="content" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-align: center">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvTechTickets" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CallNo" 
                DataSourceID="sqlDS_TechTickets" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                EmptyDataText="NO TICKETS FOR YOU!" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" 
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
          <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F0F0F0" />
          <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YOUR OPEN TICKETS">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-collapsed="True" style="width: 100%">
                <h3> 
                  <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CallNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </div>   
                  <div id="divTicketCustomerName">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700" Text='<%# Bind("Company") %>'></asp:Label>
                  </div>     
                  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="font-size: small; font-style: italic;" Text='<%# Bind("Problem") %>'></asp:Label>
                </h3>
                <p style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top">
                  <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style="font-size: small; font-style: italic;" Text='<%# Bind("Detail") %>'></asp:Label>
                </p>
              </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
          </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF9933" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource>.......</asp:SqlDataSource>
      </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good method for figuring out CSS tweaks is to use Firebug or some other DOM inspection tool to view the live code's CSS. In Firebug you can also make live tweaks to the CSS and see how it affects your layout.

I start with the element I want to tweak and then go up the DOM tree checking-out the calculated CSS values for its parents.

Sorry I can't offer any more specific help without seeing the code of the page as I'm no ASP guru.

Comment: Jasper, that's a thought however I don't see the issue until I deploy and view through an emulator or on device. In chrome - seems just fine. As for the code, it's in the Jquery Mobile css.